# Android Studio - duplicate file

Tags: android-studio

Is it possible to duplicate a file in Android Studio in the Project View?

When I right click on a file there I don't see it in any of the options.

If it's possible, how do you do it?

Answer (score 11):

I don't know any direct shortcut to do it, but you can surely go with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>. It'll open dialog similar to the following one:

[image]

Answer (score 8):

To do this in one fewer step, select the file in project view, then press F5 or alternatively go to Refactor -> Copy. Works in Android Studio 3.3.2